# MariaDB: Create and grant a new user using unix sockets plugin (passwordless)

Tags: mysql, authentication, mariadb, unix-sockets

I just installed MariaDB on Kubuntu 15.10. I am able to log in with the root user via the plugin that authenticates the user from the operating system. (This is new to me, so I am learning about it rather than removing the plugin authentication as most tutorials seem to recommend.)

Now I want to create a non-root user and grant all privileges to that user and allow the user to log into mysql (on localhost) without a password (using just the plugin). How would I do this? Do I need to give the user a password too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer. The part I needed was "IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket" as shown below:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER serg IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on mydatabase.* to 'serg'@'localhost';

MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host, password, plugin from mysql.user;
+--------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| user         | host      | password | plugin      |
+--------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| root         | localhost |          | unix_socket |
| root         | mitra     |          | unix_socket |
| root         | 127.0.0.1 |          | unix_socket |
| root         | ::1       |          | unix_socket |
| serg         | localhost |          | unix_socket |
+--------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then in the shell:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

To log in using user 'serg' do not use sudo. Just use `mysql -u serg`.

Comment: I had to add `@localhost` to the `CREATE USER...` to get it to work.  Otherwise, I would get `Can't find any matching row in the user table`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign password for that user and do the entry in my.cnf file.

- *grant all privileges on mydatabas.* to user@localhost identified by 'password' ;*

edit **my.cnf**

[mysql]

user=user

password=password

[mysqladmin]

user=user

password=password

```
sudo service mysql restart

mysql -h localhost -u user
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#creating-users):

> If SQL_MODE does not have NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER set, then you can also create the user account via GRANT. For example:

so this is enough:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON db.* TO username@hostname IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;
```